# Extending a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I generated a pandas dataframe df (see example below). As a next step, my task is to extend this dataframe with values from specific rows and columns and generate a new dataframe df2 (see example below). 
How can I generate df2 with code and not manually?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 45, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [2, 0, 45, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [3, 0, 135, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [5, 0, 135, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           columns=['trial_nr', 'mini_block_nr', 'stimulus_nr', 'CorResp', 'SR0', 'SR1', 'SR2', 'SR3', 'SR4', 'SR5'])
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 45, 1, 0, 45, 135, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 135, 0, 0, 0],
                    [2, 0, 45, 1, 0, 45, 135, 0, 0, 0],
                    [3, 0, 135, 2, 0, 45, 135, 0, 0, 0],
                    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 135, 0, 0, 0],
                    [5, 0, 135, 2, 0, 45, 135, 0, 0, 0]],
                   columns=['trial_nr', 'mini_block_nr', 'stimulus_nr', 'CorResp', 'SR0', 'SR1', 'SR2', 'SR3', 'SR4', 'SR5'])
print(df2)
```

For example, the column `SR0` represents the stimulus_nr that is associated with CorResp = 0 and mini_block_nr = 0, in this case stimulus_nr = 0. Likewise, the column SR1 represents the stimulus_nr that is associated with CorResp = 1 and mini_block_nr = 0, in this case stimulus_nr = 45.

I hope these examples illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

I really appreciate your help, many thanks!

Chris

Comment: if i understand you, in column SR0 you want the max of corresponding stimulus and that for all CorResp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Christina IIUC this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
for i in sorted(df.CorResp.unique()):
    mask=(df.CorResp==i)&(df.mini_block_nr==0)

    df['SR'+i]=df.loc[mask].stimulus_nr[0]
```

This will fill columns `SR1`  `SR5` in your DataFrame, with the values you're looking for. If there's more `CorResp` values it will still work. It's not clear if you need a more general answer or if `mini_block_nr` can take different values, though, so I can edit if that's the case

Comment: Works but not very scalable.

Comment: @Juan C, thank you so much, it's working perfectly :)

Comment: You're welcome @Christina ! If you can upvote the answer,so it is known that it works I would really appreciate it  (:

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is first to use `.pivot_table` to get all the `stimulus_nr` corresponding to `CorResp`. After that we can write a small loop to fill our columns.

The advantage of this method is that nothing is hardcoded. So if your dataframe extends to maybe 100 different values, this will still work.

Code:

```
# First we pivot our table 
pivot = df.pivot_table(values='stimulus_nr', columns='CorResp', index='trial_nr')
print(pivot)

CorResp     0     1      2
trial_nr                  
0         NaN  45.0    NaN
1         0.0   NaN    NaN
2         NaN  45.0    NaN
3         NaN   NaN  135.0
4         0.0   NaN    NaN
5         NaN   NaN  135.0

# Next for every column in pivot table we fill our corresponding SR columns
# While we do this, we fill our NaN to get values in each row.

for col in range(pivot.shape[1]):
    df[f'SR{col}'] = pivot[col].fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
print(df)

Out[40]: 
   trial_nr  mini_block_nr  stimulus_nr  CorResp  SR0   SR1    SR2  SR3  SR4  \
0         0              0           45        1  0.0  45.0  135.0    0    0   
1         1              0            0        0  0.0  45.0  135.0    0    0   
2         2              0           45        1  0.0  45.0  135.0    0    0   
3         3              0          135        2  0.0  45.0  135.0    0    0   
4         4              0            0        0  0.0  45.0  135.0    0    0   
5         5              0          135        2  0.0  45.0  135.0    0    0   

   SR5  
0    0  
1    0  
2    0  
3    0  
4    0  
5    0
```